# Milliseconds time input

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

Is there a way to implement milliseconds into a script that plots bar colors based on time?

I currently have a script that plots bar colors based on minutes:

```
ny2_session = input(title="Q2", type=input.session, defval="0400-0500:1234567")
```

Was wondering if there was a way to add milliseconds to the script for further accuracy.